# How can I merge overlapping nodes of a polygon in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, nodes

My shape is composed of 7 polygons which are supposed to be adjacent (ie sharing sharing same nodes). Would like to join the polygons by their nodes and make sure there is no space in between two polygons. But the 7 polygons maintained separately. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You want to snap them together.. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32899/snapping-two-polygons-together is that right?

Comment: What software do you want to use want to i.e you want it to be done in postgres,python or QGIS